# How do i bulk or batch update mysql in a single query

Tags: mysql

I have tried both of these methods and my table never gets updated. It just stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE localhost_campaigns.list_name_counter SET counter = (CASE purl WHEN 'dingo' THEN '1' WHEN 'koala' THEN '0' END) WHERE purl IN (dingo, koala);

UPDATE localhost_campaigns.list_name_counter SET counter = CASE WHEN purl = 'dingo' THEN '1' WHEN purl = 'koala' THEN '0' END WHERE purl IN (dingo, koala);
```

Comment: try this like  WHERE purl IN ("dingo", "koala");

Comment: Try enabling error reporting in both PHP and whatever MySQL API you are using. Not quoting your strings should produce a MySQL syntax error.

Comment: thanks @hakkikonu, that worked.

Comment: Yup...Seems like it...That it's question only `MySQL/SQL` related so then the OP should remove the php tag then.! :D

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai You can always submit an edit request yourself. Just click on the edit button under the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a real solution;

Use quotes for your strings.

like

```
UPDATE localhost_campaigns.list_name_counter 
SET counter = (CASE purl WHEN 'dingo' THEN '1' WHEN 'koala' THEN '0' END) 
WHERE purl IN ("dingo", "koala");
```